# What is the correct way in Backbone.js to listen and modify a model property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view attached to a model with an attribute "title". I want to be able to trim the value each time it is set (for some obscure reason, I don't want to do this on server-side). In my model I tried this:

```
this.on('change:title', this.trimName);
//... later on
trimName: function(){
    console.log('triggered');
    this.set({'title':$.trim(this.get('title'))}, {silent:true});
}
```

but this triggers an infinite recursion.
(Also, the recursion doesn't happen on jsfiddle, why?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You correctly make the change with `{silent:true}` which should prevent re-triggering the event. So the problem is probably somewhere else. Posting a stripped down example on jsfiddle would make it easier to find out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Like I stated, I cannot reproduce the error on jsfiddle, which is weird. Maybe it's my php file that's broken. I'll come back on it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the model do the trimming: Override the `set` method and run `Backbone.Model`'s `set` method after you trim.

> Note that this is not totally flushed out to handle an object literal, you'll need to
>   implement that yourself.  This will work for `key, value, option` parameters. View the `set` 
>   method in  Backbone's source code for an example: http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js

```
set: function(key, value, options) {
      var attrs;

      // Handle both `"key", value` and `{key: value}` -style arguments.
      if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
        attrs = key;
        options = value;
      } else {
        attrs = {};
        attrs[key] = value;
      }

      options = options || {};
      if ( options.trim ) {
          attrs[key] = $.trim( attrs[key] );
      }
      // do any other custom property changes here

      Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call( this, attrs, options ); 
}
```

Comment: I __am__ doing the trimming in the mode.
Your method works pretty well. I just have to change attrs[key] = $.trim( attrs[key] ); to make it work with the first params format.
One question though, is it a good idea to override set like this? Assuming that my method works, wouldn't it be more elegant to trigger change events?

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. In fact, once you start using `Backbone` more, you'll find yourself overriding methods like this frequently. The idea behind backbone is to give you a basic structure of powerful patterns, practices, and methods that applications frequently need.  Your job is to mold it into a working framework for your application's problem domain. You should probably consider creating a `Model` of your own that you extend in many places in your app instead of using the default `Backbone.Model`.

Comment: I added some more code to this example to make this model more reusable for models that don't want to trim, but may want other things done using the `options` key

Comment: hey there. nice solution i have edited it to support creation of new model with all his params. i.e new TrimModel({a:" some text  ",b: " another text with spaces at edges "})